# TSQL: How to make part of the query dynamic, for instance the name of the table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The application have tables that have year appended to them, i.e. `HiredEmpl2013, HiredEmpl2014, HiredEmpl2015`. The problem is that every year someone need to go make those changes even for simple queries such as

```
SELECT EmpID, FName, LName, ...
FROM HiredEmpl2013
```

I've tried something like

```
DECLARE @year INT,
        @table_source VARCHAR(50)
SET @year = 2013
SET @table_source = 'HiredEmpl' + CAST(@year AS CHAR(4))

SELECT EmpID, FName, LName, ...
FROM @table_source
```

I'm getting this error: `Must declare the table variable "@table_source".`

Is there a way I can make part of the query dynamic?

Thanks for helping

## UPDATE

I've used EXEC to dynamically calculate count in a table.

`EXEC(sql) ---> 297`

I tried to save the value, but I got an error:

```
SET @total = EXEC(@sql) --> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

Comment: Ideally put them all in 1 table with a [YEAR] column, all problems solved.  Failing that use `sp_executeSQL()`  to run a statement you build in a string.

Comment: Yeah, that's a terrible database design.  Eew.

Comment: The database was designed in 1997, and the owner wants it like that for now. There are so many flaws that will be fixed later.

Comment: @Will *Maybe* not, if the intent was to partition the data. In which case the OP should *NOT* try to access the tables directly, but use the view that combines them.

Comment: Partition or not, the way to fix this is to use a view that collects all tables with a UNION ALL and access the view, not the tables. As long as the tables have an indexed date column the query optimizer will only touch the relevant tables. Dynamic tricks are only going to add more abuse. The *table* is the most fundamental part of a query, it's not a parameter. Change the table and you change the execution plan completely

Comment: `EXEC` does not work like that it is not a function call but in any case you should ask that "UPDATE" in a new question -- it has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sp_executesql so that you can pass your output parameter. 
Following will give you the count of that table.

```
DECLARE @year INT,
        @table_source VARCHAR(50),
       @CNT INT 

DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

SET @year = 2013
SET @table_source = 'HiredEmpl' + CAST(@year AS CHAR(4))


declare @SQLString nvarchar(max)='SELECT @CNT1 = count(*) FROM ' + @table_source ;

SET @ParmDefinition = N'  @CNT1 INT OUTPUT'; 

--print @SQLString

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @CNT1 = @CNT OUTPUT;  

SELECT @CNT;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there..

use dynamic sql..

```
DECLARE @year INT,
        @table_source VARCHAR(50)
SET @year = 2013
SET @table_source = 'HiredEmpl' + CAST(@year AS CHAR(4))

declare @sql nvarchar(max)='SELECT EmpID, FName, LName FROM '+@table_source

print @sql

--exec(@SQl)
```

Comment: why is `exec(@sql)` commented out?

Comment: It's working. The only thing I don't understand is why it's not letting me store result in a variable, for instance. (see update).

Comment: There's no reason to use dynamic sql and it *does* make things more error prone. It can be avoided *very* easily by using an ORM on the client side or a view in this case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:this answer is specific to issue raised by user `m getting this error: `

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a dynamic query you want to to use a static query in your application.  You want to change as few things as possible and non-dynamic querys are easy for the server to optimize.

The best way to solve this is to change the model and make a table with the year as a column. Often people resist this change -- but I have to say it is the best choice.

**As a strong second make a current year view:**

```
CREATE VIEW HiredEmplCurrent as 
  SELECT EmpID, FName, LName, ...
  FROM HiredEmpl2016_YEAR
```

Then change all your accesses to use HiredEmplCurrent, once a year you just have to change the view.

Comment: If the tables contain a date column with min/max date constraints, the optimizer is smart enough to use only the relevant table. In fact, this is the way federated views were implemented back in SQL Server 2000, to allow spreading one query across many servers. I think the requirements are more relaxed now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - my view is just selecting from one table, I think you are taking about a view that unions all the tables.  What you say is true but I don't believe that is what the OP wants.

Comment: With a UNION ALview you don't have to pick a table at all. You just add a new table to the view each year and keep the rest of the code clean.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that is not wrong but THAT IS NOT WHAT THE USER WANTS, the user wants just the current year.